# Git cannot find file in remote despite file being there

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-remote

I have a file `project/data/data.csv` where `project/` is the parent project and `data/` is a submodule. Inside of `project/data/` I run
`git checkout origin/master data.csv`

To which git replies:

`error: pathspec 'data.csv' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

When I go to master on gitlab however, the file is very much there.

I have tried doing git reset, git fetch and git pull, none of which have fixed the issue.

Something that happened before git got crazy, was that I got a corrupted tree object. To fix this I had to remove all such objects and then do a git fetch and a git pull.

This led to the data submodule reporting a dirty object, which I fixed by deleting the .git file and doing a git pull.

After which I seemed to be able to pull and push with no issue, so i am not sure if it is related.

Any suggestions on how to get git to track the file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already had the corruption and ended up deleting .git you already tried the hard reset (assuming you already tried `git reset origin/master` and are not worried about losing any files. If that is the case try
`git clone <repo>`
and this should reinitialize your repo with the right files

Comment: Although that would be my normal approach, some current files that were modified between deleting the .git folder and the current state need to be kept.

Comment: But these files are still local, right? You could stash or physically take a backup in another directory and then re-add them once your repo is reinitialized.

Comment: Screw it, nuking the entire thing and coming clean is probably going to be better than trying to restore what I have.

Answer (score 0):

To track that file, try this:

```
git add data.csv
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't help, also that file is in the remote

Comment: Ah. Did you do a git fetch beforehand?

Comment: Yes, I did git fetch and git fetch origin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give a try for

```
git submodule update --rebase --remote
```